# Codeigniter Custom Form Validation

Tags: validation, codeigniter

this is my register method on controller to register a new user.

```
function register() {

    $config_rules = array(
            array(
                'field' => 'txtEmail',
                'label' => 'Email',
                'rules' => 'required|valid_email'
            ),
            array(
                'field' => 'txtPassword',
                'label' => 'Password',
                'rules' => 'required|min_length[6]'
            ),
            array(
                'field' => 'txtRePassword',
                'label' => 'Re-type Password',
                'rules' => 'required|min_length[6]'
            )
        );
    $this->form_validation->set_rules($config_rules);

    if(isset($_POST['btnSubmit']) && $this->form_validation->run() == TRUE)
    {
        // insert query and redirect to registration success page
    }

    $this->load->view('users/register_form');
}
```

All the rules for form validation are work fine.
But, the problem is I can't do is to validate password and re-type password.

How make a custom form validation such as to check either 
password and re-type password are same or not. Then return false for the validation and give error message telling that password and re-type password are not same through validation_errors().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify the rule something like this:

```
$rules['password'] = "required|matches[passconf]";
```

In the above example, the field `password` will be matched with password confirm field `passconf`.

See the docs for more information.

- http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html

Answer (score 2):

add:

```
matches[txtRePassword]
```

to the password rules, then you can use:

```
$this->validation->set_message('matches', 'New Passwords don\'t match');
```

to make a customer error message